# JavaScript: use defineProperty accessor on an array's .length?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome, ecmascript-5, defineproperty

I would like (mainly for academic reasons) to be able to set an accessor on an array's `length` using [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), so than I can notify for size changes.

I am aware of ES6 object observe, and watch.js, but I would like to attempt to do this in ES5 without extra libraries if possible, even if this is only for V8/Chrome.

A sample array:

```
var demoArray = ['one', 'two']
```

Alas Chrome, out of the box, makes length not configurable:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(demoArray, 'length')
Object {value: 2, writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: false}
```

And it doesn't work:

```
Object.defineProperty(demoArray, 'length', { set: function(){ console.log('length changed!')} })
```

Fails with `'TypeError: Cannot redefine property: length'`

As you can see, **`configurable`** is **`false`** - so the failure is understandable. However [according to MDN it should be possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Redefining_the_length_property_of_an_Array_object).

How can I get `defineProperty` working on an array's `length` property? Should this work?

Comment: I think the MDN page (and the links from there) only refer to redefining the `writable` property descriptor (and maybe the `value` one), but changing the data property to an accessor property is definitely prohibited.

Comment: I made an edit (after you accepted) that might clear up the MDN passage: it seems to be talking about a bug which blocks setting the `value` using `defineProperty`, which *should* be possible according to the spec, but is some implementations is sometimes blocked erroneously (as if it incorrectly had `writable: false`). However, defining a setter is right out, in compliance with the spec.

Comment: Yeah http://whereswalden.com/2013/08/05/new-in-firefox-23-the-length-property-of-an-array-can-be-made-non-writable-but-you-shouldnt-do-it/comment-page-1/#comment-162704 talks about the same thing. Setting a *data* property works fine: `Object.defineProperty(demoArray, 'length', {value: 0});` but setting an accessor property won't work and breaks the spec.

Comment: Just so people are aware, I updated the MDN page slightly to be clearer about what is/isn't allowed.  Look at page history if you want the text that was there when this question and answers were written.

`length` being redefinable doesn't mean you get a pass on all the other restrictions `Object.defineProperty` ordinarily enforces.  Specifically: until you change `length`'s writability to false, you can only change `length`'s writability and value.  You can't change the property to a getter/setter pair, ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since reading a little more about this, [Kangax's excellent article dedicated to the topic of subclassing Array](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/#wrappers_prototype_chain_injection) covers a a variety of techniques. One technique, called **Array prototype injection** is used to subclass Array in popular libraries like Ractive.js. It relies on the non-spec, but popular **__*proto*__** being exposed, but does allow 'accessors' on length.

Answer (score 3):

According to [ECMAScript 15.4.5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.1), arrays have their own `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` internal method, so the `configurable: false` is not necessarily an immediate deal-breaker. An early step in this method says:

> *3. If P is `"length"`, then*
>
> a. If the `[[Value]]` field of Desc is absent, then
>
> i. Return the result of calling the default `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` internal method (8.12.9) on A passing `"length"`, Desc, and Throw as arguments.

Therefore, if you don't have a `value` attribute in your property descriptor, the property setting operation is delegated to the default `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` method. [ECMAScript 15.4.5.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.2) requires that the `length` property have `configurable: false`, so the default method will fail.

If you *do* set `value`, to avoid dropping into the default method, you cannot also define a setter. Attempting to do so will cause an error in Chrome (or any browser in compliance with [section 8.10](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10)):

> `TypeError: Invalid property. A property cannot both have accessors and be writable or have a value`

Therefore, it seems impossible to define a setter on array `length` in any ES5-compliant implementation.

Note that the MDN article seems to be talking about browsers erroneously refusing to set the `value` using `defineProperty`, which *should* be generally possible, but sometimes is not, due to a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Would it be correct to say this essentially comes down to .length being both a data descriptor and an accessor descriptor? I've read some similar stuff here: http://whereswalden.com/2013/08/05/new-in-firefox-23-the-length-property-of-an-array-can-be-made-non-writable-but-you-shouldnt-do-it/

Comment: @nailer Mostly it just comes down to `configurable: false`. Array's custom `[[DefineOwnProperty]]` allows data descriptors with `value`. When you try to define an *accessor* descriptor (naturally, without `value`), the custom method throws you to the default method, which immediate stops you, because you're trying to violate `configurable: false`. The custom method doesn't enforce the `configurable: false` requirement, but the custom method only allows setting data descriptors with a `value` item.

Answer (score 2):

"Adding a event listener to Array.length will cause a huge impact on overall performance of your application, and you should avoid it by all means" @Juno;

"don't rely on redefining the length property of an array to either work, or to work in a particular manner" MDN;

Since we can't touch length, to have a similar behavior we can change the push method and aways use it to add new values to the array.

```
var a = ['a','b'];
a.push = function(x){
  console.log('added: ',x,', length changed: ',(this.length+1)); 
  this[this.length]=x
}
a.push('c');
```

Answer (score 2):

[rmprop.js](https://github.com/blake-regalia/rmprop.js) let's you proxy an array so that you can do whatever you want with the `.length` property:

```
var rmprop = require('rmprop');
var arr = rmprop(['my','array']);

// instead, length will return sum of lengths of all elements
Object.defineProperty(arr, 'length', {
    get: function() {
        return this[unprop.real].join('').length;
    },
};

arr.length; // 7
```

Answer (score 1):

As it clearly say on the document:

> Only Internet Explorer 9 and later, and Firefox 23 and later, appear
>   to fully and correctly implement redefinition of the length property
>   of arrays.  For now, don't rely on redefining the length property of
>   an array to either work, or to work in a particular manner.  And even
>   when you can rely on it, there's really no good reason to do so.

It is not supported by all browsers including Chrome, and you should find another way to do what you desire to do in the first place without changing `length` property of Array.

Once, a property is defined with `configurable: false`, there is really no way to change its configurations.

So in this case, it in not possible. And even if it is, it will have performance issues because `Array.length` is used everywhere by all libraries, is accessed so often, and is constantly changing everywhere.

Adding a event listener to `Array.length` will cause a huge impact on overall performance of your application, and you should avoid it by all means.

Comment: Ah, I'd missed the 'only' part of the doc I referred to. As mentioned, though, I'm not planning to monitor all objects that inherit from Array, just a single array.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Proxy" object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

no library required

Comment: This is a cool answer - Proxies are great new techand a link to the official docs is good - but StackOverflow doesn't normally accept link-only answers - can you please include a demo your answer? Thanks!